# What is the difference between resultSet.getBinaryStream() and resultSet.GetBlob().getBinaryStream() for ojdbc

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

What is the difference between `resultSet.getBinaryStream()` and `resultSet.GetBlob().getBinaryStream()` for ojdbc? Both methods return an `OracleBlobInputStream`, but `resultSet.getBinaryStream()` will set an "internalBlob" flag to true in the stream object while `getBlob().getBinaryStream()` will set it to false.  I noticed the difference when closing the stream itself.  If the flag is true the close() method will attempt to "free" the Blob object.  This adds pretty significant overhead to the closing process (about .05s in my tests) which adds up when pulling many blobs from the db.  The problem is solved when using `getBlob().getBinarySTream()` as the flag is false and the blob object is not freed.  I was just hoping anyone would be able to shed light on what the internalBlob flag is actually for, and if it matters whether the blob is freed or not.

Here is the close() method inside the OracleBlobInputStream

```java
public void close() throws IOException {
    if (!this.closed) {
        try {
            if (this.blob != null && this.internalBlob) {
                this.blob.free();
                this.internalBlob = false;
            }
        } catch (SQLException var5) {
            throw (IOException)((IOException)DatabaseError.createIOException(var5).fillInStackTrace());
        } finally {
            super.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it wouldn't do this, it would leak the blob handle, which could lead to more memory consumption (possibly both client-side and db-side). Your own code should also release the blob when it is done with it, otherwise it - potentially - continue to live until the transaction ends.